# Changes series name in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm getting names from an array in Highcharts with
`Tooltip: Pointformat: {series.name}`, but I would like to change the name right there on the spot.

Is there a way you can write `{series.name AS Blabla}` or something?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible. But you can set instead of: `{series.name}` simply: `Blabla`.

Comment: Not really, as it will then say "blabla" on every category. But thanks for the answer, now I know I don't have to look any further :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to use `tooltip.formatter`. Also, remember that for each series object you can set tooltip.pointFormat, so one series will have `Bla bla` and another `Bla ble bla`.